# TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined, Angular app built on AWS CodeBuild

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app being build on AWS CodeBuild getting the error

> /codebuild/output/src880653465/src/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/ui/index.js:56
> this.outputStream.write(data);
> ^
>
> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined**
> at UI.write (/codebuild/output/src880653465/src/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/ui/index.js:56:23)
> at UI.writeLine (/codebuild/output/src880653465/src/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/ui/index.js:69:8)

I've seen this error has been talked about here before but none of the accepted answers worked for my case. I tried all manner of `npm update -g @angular/cli` and targeting different versions or other manners of installing/updated angular, all to no avail

The app is being build via the following yml on AWS CodeBuild

```
   runtime-versions:
        nodejs: 14
    commands:
        - echo installing...
        - npm install -g @angular/cli
        - npm install
  build:
    commands:
        - echo build 
        - ng build
```

The error happens during the build step `ng build`

Installed versions from CodeBuild are

```
 copying : node/14.19.2
 installed : v14.19.2 (with npm 6.14.17)
```

My package.json has angular at version 6 `@angular/core": "6.1.0"`, yet CodeBuild shows the below note

> Your global Angular CLI version (14.1.0) is greater than your local
> version (1.7.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

Tried a few other random things like settings TypeScript versions or more ways of modifying Node or Angular version, all same results

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong to cause this odd TypeScript error? or what versions are mismatched that I can correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing this specific version of Angular CLI. Instead of

```
    commands:
        - echo installing...
        - npm install -g @angular/cli
```

specify exactly

```
    commands:
        - echo installing...
        - npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.4
```